# Reverse a word using function call

Tags: c++

How can input a word and reverse the output of it. I made a function to calculate the length of the word and from here I have to reverse the word depending on the length of it. 
How can I do that?

```
 #include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
int LengthOfString(  const  char *); // declaring prototype for length of the string 

int reverse(const char []);


int main()
{
    char string1[100];
    cout<<"Enter a string: ";
    cin>>string1;

    cout<<"Length of string is "<<LengthOfString(string1);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

int LengthOfString( const  char *x)
{
    int index;
    for(index = 0; *x!='\0';x++,index++);

    return index;
}

int reverse(const char y[])
{
/*   my attempted loop, its not right i know.
 a[] = *index; // length of the word 
        for(int i=0; i<=index/2; i++)
            for(j=0; j == length, j--) */ 

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: Have you made any attempts?  Can you show us what you think would be the solution?

Comment: @DrewShafer There's no longer a homework tag. There was some discussion of this on meta, iirc.

Comment: Work out how to reverse a string of length 0, then length 1, then length 2, then length 3, then you should be able to generalise.

Comment: What are you supposed to return in function `reverse`?  You may want to make it return `void`.

Answer (score 7):

This wheel has already been invented, and exists in the standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string word;

    std::cout << "Enter a word: ";
    std::cin >> word;

    std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());

    std::cout << "Reverse: " << word << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To understand exactly what's going on here, there are a few things that you must cover first:

- data structures (classes)
- containers
- iterators

I hope you already know what a class is.  In case you're still in introductory stuff, a class is basically a user defined collection of state and behavior.  The author can choose to restrict access to the state or behavior of a class for a variety of reasons.  In the case of `std::string`, the standard library string class, all of the state is hidden and only behavior is accessible.

The string class is a container that contains characters.  There are numerous other container classes, each of which with different strengths and weaknesses.  The string class contains a sequence of characters with a strict order.  Other containers exist, such as `std::set`, `std::vector`, `std::list`, and others.  `std::string` bears a passing resemblance to `std::vector`, and is a distant cousin of `std::list`. Each collection behaves differently and is suited for different things.

You might think you need to understand how the string class stores its data in order to reverse it, but you don't.  This is where iterators come in. `std::string` owns a typedef, `std::string::iterator`, which is a special object which stores the location of a single element in a string.  `std::reverse` is a library function which takes 2 iterators and repeatedly swaps their contents and moves them towards each other.  This looks like this as it's happening:

```
v  v       <-- positions of iterators (start at the start, end at the end)
ABC        <-- initial state

v v        <-- the end iterator moved back
ABC        

v v
CBA        <-- the iterators swapped their values

 vv        <-- the begin iterator moved forward
CBA        

 V         <-- the end iterator moved back; both iterators are in the same place
CBA        <-- therefore, we're done, the string is reversed
```

One thing about iterators is they're kind of like pointers.  In fact, you can pass pointers to some functions that expect iterators because they behave syntactically the same.  Therefore, you should be able to write your own reverse function that uses pointers that basically does the same thing this did, except with `char *`s.

Here's some pseudocode that you should be able to write the function with (I won't write it out completely because it's homework):

```
namespace BaidNation
{
    void reverse(char *begin, char *end)
    {
        loop forever
        {
            if (end equals begin):
                done;
            move end backwards;
            if (end equals begin):
                done;
            swap end's and begin's characters;
            move begin forwards;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `BaidNation::reverse` (as well as `std::reverse`) expects for end the iterator that references the element *AFTER* the end of the collection, not the one that references the last element.  How does it then make sense to use this?

Your `LengthOfString` function returns the number of non-null characters in a string.  Since arrays are zero-indexed, we know that, like any other array, if we check `string1 + LengthOfString(string1)`, we'll get a pointer to the character after the end which is, for once, exactly what we want.

Thus, we can use this to reverse the string:

```
BaidNation::reverse(string1, string1 + LengthOfString(string1));
```

If you have to use exactly the signature earlier, you can adapt this design into the other one:

```
int reverse(const char str[])
{
    char *start = str, *end = str + LengthOfString(str);
    BaidNation::reverse(start, end);
}
```

Comment: I only bother using things for longer snippets.

Comment: Also this is clearly a homework problem, so I think he wants the actual details of how.

Comment: I want to make my own function. and not use a built in

Comment: yes this is a part of my homework in which where i had to build a length function and then using that reverse the word by another function.

Comment: I would also consider `word.rend(), word.rbegin()`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that the return type of your prototype function is `int`, it looks to me like you want to do an in-place reversal of a string. You first need to find out how long the string is (although you computed that before, you didn't pass the result to this function), then swap elements until you get to the middle. To make this work you need to pass, not a `const char[]`, but just a `char*` (indicating that you will be changing the content):

```
int reverse(char* y)
{
  int ii, n;
  n = LengthOfString(y); // "no built in functions - otherwise, use strlen()
  for(ii=0; ii<n/2;ii++) {
    char temp;
    temp = y[ii];
    y[ii] = y[n - ii - 1];
    y[n - ii] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't use any built in functions.
n = strlen(y);

Comment: So use the one you already wrote... `LengthOfString(y)` - I have modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: quick question, can you define a function in another function?

Comment: "Can you define a function in another function"? No. You certainly can USE a function that you defined in another function - as long as the compiler knows, when it gets there, what the PROTOTYPE of that function is. This is the reason for putting a statement like `int LengthOfString(char* s);` at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new char* of the same length, and then loop as follows -

```
for(int i=0;i<stringLength;i++){
    newString[i]=oldString[stringLength-i];
}
return newString;
```

Also you might want to consider using the String class instead of char*.

Comment: I have to iterate the word ++ depending on the length and reiterate it again --

Comment: @BaidNation Im not really sure what you mean by that. Do you understand my solution at least and how to implement it?

Comment: why did u do, <newString[i]=oldString[stringLength-i];>

Comment: @BaidNation Trace the loop and you will see. When i=0 the 0th (first) letter of newString will be the stringLength-0 th (last) letter of oldString, thus it is reversed. When i=1 the second letter of newString is the second to last of oldString, etc etc.

Comment: I think you need `newString[i]=oldString[stringLength - i - 1]` since `stringLength` is the number of non-null characters. There is also the BIG problem of returning a variable that was dynamically allocated inside a function (hint: it results in undefined behavior).

Comment: If you use variables that aren't in the question, you should show how they're defined.  This can't just be dropped in place in the existing reverse, since the return type is not the same.  As @floris mentioned, you swap the null terminator to the front of the string, which is semantically valid but doesn't make sense.  Also, the first character of the original string is never copied.